# forceignore - Correct syntax for excluding not yet synced remote changes - CustomField, Profile, RecordType, CustomObjectTranslation

Tags: salesforcedx, .forceignore

I need some help figuring out the correct syntax for excluding the remote changes in my scratch org, not yet synced with local source.  These are dependency changes that I'm importing via `force:mdapi:deploy` and I do not want them appearing when I run `force:source:status`.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm) is really vague on this:

> #### Exclude Remote Changes Not Yet Synced with Your Local Source
>
> Sometimes, you make a change directly in a scratch org but you don’t want to pull that change into your local DX project. To exclude remote metadata changes, use the format [api name].[metadata type] in .forceignore.
> If you have a permission set named “dreamhouse,” add dreamhouse.permissionset to .forceignore.

As an example, to exclude `Contact.Primary_Academic_Program__c` here's what I tried:

- `Contact.customfield`: does not work even though [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) is the API name.
- `Contact.field`: excludes *all* contact fields, but that's too generic.

The changes I'm trying to exclude are as below.  Can someone provide me the an example of the correct forceignore syntax for excluding one item of each different item type listed below?

```
STATE       FULL NAME                                   TYPE                     PROJECT PATH
──────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────────────  ────────────
Remote Add  Contact.Primary_Academic_Program__c         CustomField
Remote Add  Contact.Primary_Department__c               CustomField
Remote Add  Contact.Primary_Educational_Institution__c  CustomField
Remote Add  Contact.Primary_Sports_Organization__c      CustomField
Remote Add  Admin                                       Profile
Remote Add  Account.Academic_Program                    RecordType
Remote Add  Account.Administrative                      RecordType
Remote Add  Account.Business_Organization               RecordType
Remote Add  Account.Educational_Institution             RecordType
Remote Add  Account.HH_Account                          RecordType
Remote Add  Account.Sports_Organization                 RecordType
Remote Add  Account.University_Department               RecordType
Remote Add  Account-ca                                  CustomObjectTranslation
Remote Add  Account-en_GB                               CustomObjectTranslation
Remote Add  Account-es                                  CustomObjectTranslation
Remote Add  Account-fr                                  CustomObjectTranslation
Remote Add  Contact                                     CustomObject
Remote Add  Contact-ca                                  CustomObjectTranslation
Remote Add  Contact-en_GB                               CustomObjectTranslation
Remote Add  Contact-es                                  CustomObjectTranslation
Remote Add  Contact-fr                                  CustomObjectTranslation
```

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find a solution?